# Copying clipboard-content to file automatically and continiously?

Tags: linux-mint, text, clipboard

I need to make a list of some links on a web-page.  I've been using right-click `copy link URL` and then pasting it (Menu_Edit->Paste) into `vim` running in `xterm` -- then repeating.  This is obviously a rather cumbersome approach, and surely there must be a better way.  (The pasting goes fine, so I guess the links are stored as ascii-text.)

So is there a way to automatically "record" each `copy link URL` (onto the clipboard) to a file - Ie. copying each change in the clipboard to a file?  Is there a program that can do this, or perhaps some hidden file (eg. a named pipe) from which I could read the clipboard content?

I see there are some "clipboard managers"... are any of them suited to do something like this?  (which one?  how?)

I'm using LinuxMint MATE.

Comment: Try asking a question, about extracting links from web pages. It may be easier to use a command line web page fetcher such as `wget` or `curl`.

Comment: There are already recorded into the clipboard, you just have to get them out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
while xclip -o -sel c && echo; do
  xclip -i -quiet -sel c <> /dev/null >&0 2>&0
done > file
```

`xclip -o -sel c` dumps the content of the `CLIPBOARD` selection. `xclip -i -quiet -sel c` claims ownership of the `CLIPBOARD` selection (and makes it empty) until something else claims it again. If you have a clipboard manager running, you may want to disable it as it would probably interfere.